# how to create a mac operating system pendrive on a chromebook

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, conversion, chromebook, installer

I'm trying to create a Macosx (pendrive, installer, downloadable file), for a wiped Macbook Air on a Chromebook. Using the base Chromebook operating system, it's rather foreign to me and I do not understand how to work it.

Also, the Macbook cannot download off the internet it has problems when I try to connect to the internet so an internet download is improbable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I doubt you'll manage it from a Chromebook. Windows at least has TransMac which some people manage to press into shape to make macOS installers. Unless there's a chrome equivalent, you're stuck. Concentrate on getting the Mac connected. Use Ethernet rather than WiFi. We need to know the precise Mac model, what OS was on it last & what error you get when connecting.

Comment: It requires [quite some tinkerin](https://gist.github.com/coolaj86/9834a45a6c21a41e8882698a00b55787)[g](https://web.archive.org/web/20230330055824/https://gist.github.com/coolaj86/9834a). ChromeOS has an underlying Linux system with which you can interact through the [terminal](https://chromeos.dev/en/productivity/terminal). If you're not familiar with the command line it might be easier to find someone with a working macOS and create the [bootable installe](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)[r](https://web.archive.org/web/20230607192726/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) with them.

Comment: @cachius - interesting find. Instructions look somewhat similar to building one in macOS Terminal. tbh, I'd still concentrate on getting the Mac properly internet-connected if at all possible.